# Can you have a vector of templated objects with different template types?

Tags: c++

I am wondering if there is a way to have a vector of templated objects with different template types
example

```
    template<class T>
    class object
    {
    public:
        void function()
        {

        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        std::vector<object> v;
        v.push_back(object<int>());
        v.push_back(object<char>());
        v.push_back(object<const char*>());
    }
```

I get the following error "argument list for class template "object" is missing".
I understand that I need to pass a type for the template, but is it possible to hold a collection of objects with varying template types?
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you have a limited about of them you can use a vector of std::variant, otherwise you might have to use a vector of std::any

Comment: Another possibility is to let the object class inherit from a non templated super class. That enables you to save pointer to object in your vector.

Comment: No. The template argument is part of the type, you can't leave it out. There is no such thing as just an `object` so you can't create a `std::vector` of them.

Comment: Are you asking about polymorphism?   I have used the inheritance (suggested by gerum) in several embedded systems.  A std::vector<T> contains multiple objects, each can be different, but all inherit from an fixed class (i.e. T, describing a fixed 'interface' to access each element),

Comment: This wouldn't work even with polymorphism. The objects would be sliced to the vector element type. You'd still have to use a vector of pointers rather than a vector of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others can correct me if I am wrong but I think you have 3 options.

1. Use a Variant. You don't provide a lot of details but if you cannot live with a defined set of possible values this may be too limiting.
2. Use inheritance/polymorphism.  You could declare some virtual class and have all your stored object implement that class.  Your example code will not work with that as int and char are not objects and would need a wrapper.
3. Just go full C and store everything as a void*. This is probably a bad idea.

If you provide details of what you plan to store it would be easier to advise you.

Comment: I only have a limited amount of types I would need, but I am confused about variants. I cant find any good sources, so can you give me an example or article?

Comment: This is a fairly clean example: https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/06/variant.html  You can see they declare a std::variant<int, float, std::string> intFloatString and a simple visitor to show how you might want to access the data.